# C# Program crashes when removing item from ListBox

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I am using a BindingList as a datasource for my ListBox.

```
    public static BindingList<memo> memosList = new BindingList<memo>();
```

Whenever I attempt to remove the selected object (via a button), my program crashes.

```
    private void editMemo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Remove(listBox1.SelectedItem);
    }
```

I get the following error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in
>   System.Windows.Forms.dll
>
> Additional information: Items collection cannot be modified when the
>   DataSource property is set.

I have also tried to use:

```
    private void editMemo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2.memosList.Remove(listBox1.SelectedIndex);
    }
```

however this will not allow me to compile.

What can I do to remove the item without throwing an exception?

Comment: Do you want to read the data into a list and then have that list bound to the listbox? Right now you are trying to remove from the listbox (and the dataSource).

Comment: for the second one, you want `RemoveAt`, I think, if you're specifying an index.

Answer (score 2):

You should remove the item from the BindingList that you have binded to the DataSource of your list

```
private void editMemo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(listBox1.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        BindingList<memo> bl = listBox1.DataSource as BindingList<memo>;
        bl.Remove(listBox1.SelectedItem as memo) ;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a method which displays the entire object in labels when an item in the listbox is clicked;____________________________________________________________________________________private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            memo memo = (memo)listBox1.SelectedItem;
            lblTitle.Text = memo.memoTitle.ToString();
            lblPriority.Text = memo.memoPriority.ToString();
            lblDescription.Text = memo.memoDescription.ToString();
        }
This still throws the error when the item is removed :S

Comment: http://www.codeshare.io/qH0ml I've added that bit of code to codeshare so its easier to read xD If I delete the code to display the item details in labels, it works fine, but otherwise all 3 throw exceptions.

Comment: What exception? Null Reference Exception? When you remove an item the selected item is reset and probably the SelectedIndexChanged is raised without any SelectedItem. Add `if(!listBox.SelectedItem == null) { fill the labels with the selecteditem} else { clear the labels}`